# Working with large number of fields in kibana

Tags: node.js, kibana, kibana-5

Is there a way to filter through the entries in the "Fields" dropdown in Kibana under the Visualize tab?

My data has over 1000 fields and so its not convenient having to scroll through a really long dropdown menu (that looks like below) - just to pick a field thats buried in there somewhere.

[image: kibana visualize dropdown]

Is there a way to make it searchable like how it is in the discover page for indexes and for fields - as seen below:

[image: kibana discover search box]

I am open to other suggestions as well - if there is a different way to achive the same result -  i.e., to pick fields to visualize when there are a lot of fields to pick from.

I am using Kibana 5.4.1 on Windows

Comment: You will have that feature in the next kibana version,I think 5.6 or 6

Comment: Ah, good to know. :) Any links/sources? If there is a alpha/beta then I'd like to try it out right now...

Comment: Go to https://github.com/elastic/kibana and clone the repository

Comment: Great. I downloaded alpha2 of both ES and Kibana and its got this exact feature. Thanks a lot @Lax. I think you can post your comment as an answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://github.com/elastic/kibana and clone the repository, it's in 6 version